# Move a config file into etc folder(of Karaf) when a (Maven)bundle is deployed

Tags: maven, pom.xml, apache-karaf

I want to move a cfg file into the etc folder of karaf whenever a bundle is deployed.
the cfg file is in under src/main/resource .i tried the following in the pom but its not working.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                    <copy file="src/main/resources/test.cfg" tofile="${env.KARAF_HOME}/etc/test.cfg"/>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solution could be:
- put your test.cfg file in a more specific folder. (eg: src/main/resources/cfg)
- use the maven resources plugin

This is a working example based on the maven phase generate-resources (replace that phase by deploy in your case):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-to-karaf</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/cfg</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <outputDirectory>D:\apache-karaf-3.0.1\etc\</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```